# How to create a customized ubuntu live cd

Tags: customization, live-cd

The answers to my question are all very old and the links are obsolete. As of today, what is the guide link for doing this?  I am using this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization   but since one week it gives me errors when I run the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor apparmor-utils bridge-utils libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system libguestfs-tools qemu-kvm virt-manager
```

Error message is :

```
 Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.38-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:8fad93c854562c08a10fa17f12a96ebce6223d788d0ba9d50822506dde98fa1643f25bf6f34a2d5c750f572750e11e451b935d3deb63b661a60d56feae523a1b
    - SHA256:5fe748d882a17fa29e84a9b8e28768801483628c4cdfdc167f2c59864b8b57ca
    - SHA1:b55049109617daed0cb3a1cae3c17d2eb93146b7 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4bc7fb1604a5ced117b051f7a1dfc92e [weak]
    - Filesize:2327818 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:73045820ed30428bec4d7841450a96b79e50b5708d1fd8757327985252123cc8dc6f7cffcdff80e6688842eec4fe34532dcecca29e7e2d23e47f430e9ff509af
    - SHA256:e6ddf963fedd806214d9290d35fe73c1d55aa218ebf375ffa7917d6b34c1868e
    - SHA1:dddcdbe39eafc7423f362319dfed6e260f1323ab [weak]
    - MD5Sum:1900cad2c0ad823fbb6959eb1a65475a [weak]
    - Filesize:2327818 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 24 May 2023 09:51:18 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So please tell me the updated link for customization help and also explain why I am getting this error repeatedly for last 4 days.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of customization you need. Do you need a custom iso file / DVD disk, or would it be OK with a custom USB pendrive (or even better a USB SSD)? If a pendrive or SSD would be OK, please consider a **persistent live** Ubuntu system, which can be made easily with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). Otherwise, I know that many people use **Cubic** to create a custom Ubuntu iso file (and you can make a DVD from it, if it is small enough to fit in the storage available on the DVD disk).